# how to remove horizontal scroll bar in listview in .net compact framework

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, pocketpc

i am using listview while developing windows mobile 5.0 application. When items are added at the end it shows vertical as well as horizontal scrollbar. How can remove horizontal scrollbar?

Answer (score 1):

Just adjust the width of Listview.
That is if you have a list view with width 50 and there is five columns. The sum of widths of columns should be less than or equal to 45. So you can get a 5 at end and the horizontal scroll is not shown. Horizontal scroll is only visible if u drag a header.